# Xcode StoryBoard Button Group with rounded corner

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

How can I make a button group with rounded corner

[image: Rounded Corner Button Group]

I know that I can use images. But is it possible to make it without using images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From storyboard:

Table View

Content->Static Cells

Style->Grouped

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View